# Как проверить input на пустую строку и как убрать NaN?

Tags: javascript

Есть генератор случайного числа с двумя input'ами, если вводить в них значение то все хорошо работает, но если поля остались пустыми то выдает NaN, как это исправить или вывести `alert('Введите значения')` ? Пробовал сделать: `else if (min == '') { min = 1 }` или `else if (min.value == '') { min = 1 }` но ничего не работает

```js
let inp1 = document.querySelector('.inp1');
let inp2 = document.querySelector('.inp2');
let out = document.querySelector('.out');
let btn = document.querySelector('.btn');

btn.addEventListener('click', randomNumber);

function randomNumber () {
    let min = parseInt(inp1.value);
    let max = parseInt(inp2.value);

    if (min == max) {
        max++;
    } else if (min > max) {
        max = min + 1;
    }

    inp1.value = min;
    inp2.value = max;

    out.innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #141414;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
}

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.input {
    margin: 20px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="out">0</div>
  <div class="input">
    <input type="number" class="inp1">
    <input type="number" class="inp2">
  </div>
  <button class="btn">Сгенерировать</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение заключается в том, что нужно задать значения min и max по умолчанию:

```
function randomNumber () {

    let min = 0; // минимальное значение по умолчанию
    let max = 100; // максимальное значение по умолчанию

    // меняем значения по умолчанию только тогда, когда input заполнен
    if (inp1.value != '') { min = parseInt(inp1.value); }
    if (inp2.value != '') { max = parseInt(inp2.value); }

    if (min == max) {
        max++;
    } else if (min > max) {
        max = min + 1;
    }

    inp1.value = min;
    inp2.value = max;

    out.innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}
```

Comment: Не совсем корректный ответ. Если пользователь захочет указать значение с минусом? Есть возможность проверять пустое поле таким способом: if(!inp1.value){...}. Если не ошибаюсь, должно сработать)